# Word for 'related to whales'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for 'related to whales'? I'm looking for something comparable to peristeronic (related to pigeons).

Comment: Adjective "Cetacean"

Comment: Try Googling `"of or relating to <noun>"` to get the adjectival form of that noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjective is ***cetacean.***

> Relating to or denoting cetaceans.
>
> — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cetacean)

> *cetacean*, n.
> A marine mammal of the order Cetacea; a whale, dolphin, or porpoise.
>
> *ibid.*